# streaming in sparkR?

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, sparkr

I have been using Spark in Scala for a while. I am now looking into pySpark and SparkR. I don't see streaming mentioned for PySpark and SparkR. Does any one know if you can do Spark streaming when using Python and R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark is now supporting pySpark streaming in 1.3. And an implementation of SparkR streaming can be found in https://github.com/hlin09/spark/tree/SparkR-streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of Spark 1.1), Spark Streaming is only supported in Scala & Java. If you have a specific R program or Python program you want to use you can take a look at the pipe interface on RDDs along with the transform function on DStreams. This is a bit awkward but its probably the easiest way to use Python or R code in Spark Streaming currently.

Comment: Python support for Spark Streaming should be added really soon!  There's an open pull request for it: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2538

Answer (score 0):

sparkR streaming is not available till latest version apache spark 2.1.1

but we can use sparkR streaming from github

**https://github.com/hlin09/spark/tree/SparkR-streaming**

build spark using mvn then you can be able to do sparkR streaming.